# transactional journey not triggered via postman

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, transactional-messaging-api

I created my first **transactional journey**, token request is working but
when I try to trigger it I am getting a 400 bad request.
here is the request:

```
https://[subdomain].rest.marketingcloudapis.com/messaging/v1/email/messages/[email customerkey]
```

and here the body:

```
{​
"definitionKey": "[Event Definition Key]",
"recipient":
{​​
"contactKey": "000011111aaa",
"to": "myemail@mail.com"
}​​
}​​
```

please what am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm this works:

```
{{restEndpoint}}/messaging/v1/email/messages/{{$guid}}
```

Headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{accessToken}}
```

Body:

```
{
  "definitionKey": "abcde",
  "recipient":
  {
   "contactKey": "subscriberKey12345",
    "to": "myUser@mydomain.com",
    "attributes": {
      "UserAttribute_1": "value_1",
      "UserAttribute_n": "value_n"
    }
  }
}
```

optionally also without attributes

```
{
  "definitionKey": "abcde",
  "recipient":
  {
   "contactKey": "subscriberkey12345",
    "to": "myUser@mydomain.com"
  }
}
```

This looks pretty similar to your code, so maybe the error is inside your variables.

1. Please ensure the [ ] are not physically in your code.
   "abcde" in my example is the event definition key of my journey.
2. {{$guid}} in my example is a POSTMan standard to create a unique identifier for the sendout event, and is NOT the same as the email customerkey. This is a reference number that you set by sending the request for the sendout, not any existing IDs or key from inside SFMC.